# mysql gem issue on bundle install

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails app. When I do `bundle install`, I am getting

> Make sure that gem install mysql2 -v '0.4.4' succeeds before bundling.

I am getting below error

> E: Unable to locate package libmysqlclient-devgem E: Unable to locate
>   package install E: Unable to locate package mysql2

When I do `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`

I get below error.

> The following packages have unmet dependencies: libmysqlclient-dev :
>   Depends: libmysqlclient18 (= 5.5.49-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) but
>   10.0.25+maria-1~trusty is to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I am not sure what's wrong. Please help.

Comment: Sounds like your distribution is unhappy. This isn't specifically a programming question though.

Comment: I did put it on `askubuntu` but even there everyone is unhappy. So posted it here.

Comment: You're going to get even more unhappy people here, sadly, since it's not programming related. Tough spot to be in! It does say you have broken packages, so that's something to try and fix.

Comment: try gem update --system

Comment: @Boltz0r nah, I tried that already. didn't work either